# Ember: hooking into ActionHandler#send

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to instrument `this.send()` in Ember, by hooking into `ActionHandler#send` as follows:

```
Ember.ActionHandler.reopen({
  send() { console.log("hooked"); this._super(...arguments); }
}
```

When I call this from `app.js`, as the app is starting up, it works. When I call it from an initializer, it does not. When I call it after the app starts up, such as from the application controller, it doesn't work either. In both cases where it doesn't work, if I trace into a `this.send()` call, it goes directly into the original implementation of `send`.

I have a suspicion this has something to do with the way mixins are used when instantiating objects, but otherwise I'm stumped.

Comment: So, what do you want? You want this to work when hooking in initializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work when using initializer:

> initializers/action-hook.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function initialize() {
  Ember.ActionHandler.reopen({
    send() {
      console.log("hooked");
      this._super(...arguments);
    }
  });
}

export default {
  name: 'action-hook',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Tested in application controller.

> controllers/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  afterInit: Ember.on('init', function() {
    Ember.run.next(() => {
      console.log('Send action.');
      this.send('exampleAction');
    });
  }),
  actions: {
    exampleAction() {
      console.log('exampleAction handled');
    }
  }
});
```

It outputs:

> Send action.
>
> hooked
>
> exampleAction handled

[Working demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/d04d6f50fe29f7f392b5) and [full code behind it](https://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/d04d6f50fe29f7f392b5).